# Converting lines of a file into a list of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm trying to read lines of a file into a list so every `N` lines will be in the same tuple. Assuming the file is valid so there are `xN` lines, how can I achive it?

The way I read the lines into the list:

```
def readFileIntoAList(file,N):
    lines = list()
    with open(file) as f:
        lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]
    return lines
```

What change I have to do with `N` so it will be a list of tuples so each tuple is of length `N`? For example I have the following file content:

```
ABC
abc xyz
123
XYZ
xyz abc
321
```

The output will be:

```
[("ABC","abc xyz","123"),("XYZ,"xyz abc",321")]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks)

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a [chunking function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/312464/):

```
def readFileIntoAList(file, n):
    with open(file) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        return [lines[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(lines), n)]
```

This will split the list of lines in the file into evenly sized chunks.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be:

```
>>> data = []
>>> N = 3
>>> with open('/tmp/data') as f:
...     while True:
...         chunk = []
...         for i in range(N):
...             chunk.append(f.readline().strip('\n'))
...         if any(True for c in chunk if not c):
...             break
...         data.append(tuple(chunk))
...
>>> print(data)
[('ABC', 'abc xyz', '123'), ('XYZ', 'xyz abc', '321')]
```

Note that this assumes the file has the right number of lines. Having the wrong number of lines in the above code can lead to infinite loop. A solution without that risk is:

```
data = []
N = 3
with open('/tmp/data') as f:
    i = 0
    chunk = []
    for line in f:
        chunk.append(line.strip('\n'))
        i += 1
        if i % N == 0 and i != 0:
            data.append(tuple(chunk))
            chunk = []
```

Both of these ways will not read the whole file in memory which should be more efficient when you process large datasets

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, since OP is looking to chunk by a variable number of lines.

Comment: True... missed that! Fixing - trying to find a way that does not require reading the whole file...

Comment: More "pythonic" will be to use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) for indexing instead of manual increment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`itertools.islice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
from itertools import islice

N = 3  # chunk size
with open("filename") as f:
    lines = []
    chunk = tuple(s.strip() for s in islice(f, N))
    while chunk:
        lines.append(chunk)
        chunk = tuple(s.strip() for s in islice(f, N))
```

Also you can use [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) if you prefer functional style:

```
chunk = tuple(map(str.strip, islice(f, N)))
```

Comment: @urban, you can check [Itertools Recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes).

Answer (score -1):

```
import math
def readFileIntoAList(file,N):
    lines= list()
    lines1 = list()
    with open(file) as f:
        lines1 = [lineNew.rstrip("\n") for lineNew in f]
        for a in range(math.ceil(len(lines1)/N)):
            lines.append((*lines1[a*N:(a+1)*N],))
    return lines
```

I used loop, I tried to make it easily.

Comment: You have nested list while list of tuples required.

Comment: I am sorry , I misunderstood I hope It is true.

Comment: You can use `len(lines) // N` instead of `math.ceil()`. Also, read docs of [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range), it'll help you to remove `sayac` from your code. And it still produce list of lists instead of list of tuples.

Comment: Can't you test?

Comment: I tried your changes,I remove math.ceil,sayac and made //

Comment: [Here](https://repl.it/repls/NanoFamousSphere) is what I've told you about.

Comment: Thanks for your heIp.I understand you but I want to try it by using different ways.